# Testing loss of internet connection in Expo Go on iPhone

Tags: expo, metro-bundler, expo-go

I am building a react-native application and am using Expo Go to test everything on my iPhone.  I need to test an alert that occurs when the app loses internet connectivity, however when I put my phone in airplane mode it disconnects from Metro and I lose connection with my local setup on my mac.  How do I test this out using an iPhone, Exp Go, and Metro?